# How do I turn on VTK_USE_QVTK in VTK 6.0?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, vtk

In VTK 5.X, VTK_USE_QVTK is used. However, this is not found in VTK 6.0. VTK appears to be in groups. How do I turn on VTK_USE_QVTK?

The command I'm using is sudo ccmake ..\VTK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch on VTK_GROUP_QT, and probably fiddle with the Module_vtk*Qt ones if you want fine grained control (like turning QtSQL support would be Module_vtkGUISupportQtSQL).